# convert data:image/webp;base64 to image

Tags: image, python-3.x, reactjs, base64, webcam

I am unable to convert the image captured in HTML using javascript to an Image file.

I am using a python server (python 3 +).

The following is my React JS code to capture image

```
var React = require ('react')
var Webcam = require('react-webcam')
var Test = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {};
},
capture:function(){
    var screenshot = this.refs.webcam.getScreenshot();
    this.setState({screenshot:screenshot});
    console.log("screenshot location is ",screenshot)

},
send_to_server:function(){
    RPC.execute("gold.setting","upload_webcam_blob",[this.state.screenshot],{},function(err,data) {
        if (err){
            alert(err);
            return
        }
    }.bind(this));
},
render:function(){
    console.log("apple",this.state)
    return <div>
        <Webcam ref='webcam'/>
        <button onClick={this.capture} >Capture</button>
        { this.state.screenshot ? <img src={this.state.screenshot} /> : null }
        <button onClick={this.send_to_server} >Send To Server</button>
    </div>;
},
});

module.exports= Test;
```

The value of the screenshot is something like the folliwing 
    `data:image/webp;base64,UklGRuYmAABXRUJQVlA4INomAABwPgGdASqAAuA......` 
I believe it is a base64 encode.

I send the code to the python server so i can convert to to image and save it.

Here is my python code

```
def upload_webcam_blob(self,blob,context={}):
    fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
    fh.write(blob.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()
```

updae: The above code does create a file but is empty. (this code is bad X)

Can anyone suggest what am i missing ? or any correct way to convert image and store it from the above format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better idea would be to specify the screenshot format using the option `screenshotFormat` when using react-webcam (set it to `image/png`) and use this Python code to save data to a PNG file:

```
from base64 import b64decode

def upload_webcam_blob(self, blob, context={}):
    with open('imageToSave.png', 'wb') as fh:
        # Get only revelant data, deleting "data:image/png;base64,"
        data = blob.split(',', 1)[1]
        fh.write(b64decode(data))
```

Comment: I currently get the error, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'" .  The variable blob is string and the way you split is working except for the decode.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the content of `blob` using `print(repr(blob))`?

Comment: i think you missed some header ! How will be sure file is correct if haven't any content_size arguments !

Comment: @Tiger-222 here is the link to gist with blob content
https://gist.github.com/sidzan/4b28492ee7534b59a209530d5ca7152c

Comment: @dsgdfg, all headers are contained into the base64 encoded data.

Comment: @SijanShrestha, there is issue when using WEBP, can you try to set the format to PNG or even JPEG?

Comment: I am still receiving AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' with the the updated code of yours. Am i missing something :( ?
https://gist.github.com/sidzan/7c0e8826a22d94ac52351e4998f6e17d is my python file

Comment: Ah OK, you're using Python 3. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes i am using python3, and yes the code works ! Thanks a lot ! cheers